# Single quotes for strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014-express

```
DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(200) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';

DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @XMT_TEXT AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @XMT_TEXT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(''''+ @rpmProvider + '''', ', ', '|'), ',', '</X><X>'), '|', ', ')
SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + @XMT_TEXT + '</X>') as xml)


SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as value
FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N);
```

My output :

```
1. 'Prudhvi, raj
2. Lalith, Kumar'
```

Expected output :

```
1. 'Prudhvi, raj'
2. 'Lalith, Kumar'
```

Comment: Why do you add tags of 3 different sql-server versions? Just tag the one you use! Thanks

Comment: The *actual* question is how to parse a string containing paired values. The best option is to do so *before* the string reaches the server. SQL, the language, isn't suitable for string manipulation.

Comment: If you *remove* all code related to XML and just leave `select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(''''+ @rpmProvider + '''', ', ', '|'), ',', '</X><X>'), '|', ', ')` you'll see there are no quotes around `</X><X>`. Change the replacement string to `'''</X><X>'''`, with two single quotes before and after the tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like below

```
 DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(200) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';

DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @XMT_TEXT AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @XMT_TEXT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(''''+ @rpmProvider + '''', ', ', '|'), ',', '</X><X>'), '|', ', ')
SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + @XMT_TEXT + '</X>') as xml)


SELECT case when left( N.value('.', 'varchar(50)'),1)=''''  then '' else
'''' end + N.value('.', 'varchar(50)')  +
case when right( N.value('.', 'varchar(50)'),1)=''''  then '' else
'''' end as value
FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N);



 value
'Prudhvi, raj'
'Lalith, Kumar'
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a733473d83f5c5b44730f5f72874c5a1)

Comment: Output from your query is  1. 'Prudhvi, raj'
2. Lalith, Kumar' and It is not working for the 2nd string Sir !

Comment: @Prithveeraaj check the edited answer with demo link

Comment: @Prithveeraaj You should have accepted https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377202/11683.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all code related to XML and just leave

```
DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(200) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(''''+ @rpmProvider + '''', ', ', '|'), ',', '</X><X>'), '|', ', ')
```

You'll see there are no quotes around . The result is

```
'Prudhvi, raj</X><X>Lalith, Kumar'
```

You can fix this by changing the replacement string to `''</X><X>''`, with two single quotes before and after the tags :

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(''''+ @rpmProvider + '''', ', ', '|'), ',', '''</X><X>'''), '|', ', ')
```

The result now is :

```
'Prudhvi, raj'</X><X>'Lalith, Kumar'
```

This code is *very* fragile though. It depends whitespace to separate keys, values and pairs. SQL, the language, is very weak when it comes to string parsing and manipulation. This kind of parsing should be done *before* the data gets stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query,

```
DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(200) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';

DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @XMT_TEXT AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @XMT_TEXT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(''''+ @rpmProvider + '''', ', ', '|'), ',', '''</X><X>'''), '|', ', ')
SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + @XMT_TEXT + '</X>') as xml)


SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as value
FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(200) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';

DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @XMT_TEXT AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @XMT_TEXT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @rpmProvider , ', ', '|'), ',', '</X><X>'), '|', ', ')

SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + @XMT_TEXT + '</X>') as xml)


SELECT ''''+N.value('.', 'varchar(50)')+'''' as value
FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N);
```